# clarification on recipe names when including them in chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I want some clarification when using `include_recipe`.

First of all am I correct in assuming that

`include_recipe "cookbook-name::recipe"`

is invalid because of `-` and that it should be a `_`.

Second of all
where exactly is `cookbook-name` generated or set so I can change it.

I've looked but I can't find the answer in google and truth is I'm a bit tired (so I'm not firing on all cylinders) so I'm having a little trouble thinking of an answer to what's probably some simple questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your assumption is incorrect.
It is possible to have a cookbook name with a `-` like `cookbook-name`.

The cookbook name is defined in the `metadata.rb` file.

Getting the `apt`cookbook as an example (https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/apt), the cookbook name is defined here: https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/apt/blob/master/metadata.rb#L1

Comment: Thanks, I really just wanted some confirmation to potential reason as to why my cookbook isn't working as intended, I thought it might be the first thing I mentioned. As I was unable to find the infomation on google and I'm pretty tired at the moment I decided to just ask on stack.

Comment: With a refreshed head you might have solved your problem. Otherwise you should start a new thread here and include some information regarding the actual problem ;-)

Comment: For what it's worth, underscores are preferred over dashes for cookbook names, due to them being harder to represent in ruby, and so making them more difficult [to use](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-2619) and [to test](https://github.com/sethvargo/chefspec#testing-lwrps) in Chef resources and providers.

Comment: I see, well I figured out what the problem ultimately was, it was an infrastructure issue that was causing the new cookbook to not be promoted to dev and so wasn't getting run, that's fixed and it's now working (well, still have bugs but it's unrelated). But again, thanks for the help